# Charge conjugation operator in second quantization

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, antimatter, second-quantization, charge-conjugation

How can we write charge conjugation operator's action in second quantization's formalism? I don't know if I am explaining it correctly or not but I am interested in finding how can we write fermionic creation (annihilation) operator $c_{i,\alpha}^\dagger$ ($c_{i,\alpha}$) after charge conjugation ($C$) operator's action i.e. what is $Cc_{i,\alpha}^\dagger C^\dagger$ and $Cc_{i,\alpha}C^\dagger$? where $i$ is showing the i-th site that have two states $\alpha=+1$ or $\alpha= -1$, one can say that alpha is showing spin up and spin down of a fermion.

Comment: You do not say enough about your theory to give a specific answer. The generic answer would be that $Cc^\dagger_{i,\alpha}C^{-1}=\xi c^{c\dagger}_{i,\alpha}$ where the operator on the right-hand side creates an antiparticle at the $i$-th site in state $\alpha$. $\xi$ is called the charge conjugation parity.